Readable Secondary as Yes in AlwaysOn Availability Groups in SQL Server
What impact will have selecting Yes for Readable Secondary in AlwaysOn Availability Group?
I have always used 'No' for Readable Secondary when setting AlwaysOn Availability Group.
If I am setting up two environments, Production and DR, and in DR it is set to Yes, will SharePoint will work (in read only mode obviously)

